# For Python support, what company would be best to get hosting from?

Tags: python, web-hosting, wsgi

I want to be able to run WSGI apps but my current hosting restricts it. Does anybody know a company that can accommodate my requirements?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My automatic response would be [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com/).

I haven't personally hosted with them, but they are primarily Python-oriented (founded by the guy who wrote CherryPy, for example, and as far as I know they were the first to roll out [Python 3.0 support](http://blog.webfaction.com/python-3-0-is-here)).

Comment: I can second this reccomendation. I've been a happy webfaction user for years. Very easy to deploy Django apps through their control panel either using mod_py or mod_wsgi

Comment: I also use webfaction. Don't forget to give my username on registration so I can get a bonus. :D

Comment: Yep, I use WebFaction for Python hosting too; they're great.

Answer (score 5):

I am a big fan of [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/) -- you get root access to a virtual server that takes about 2 minutes to install from stock OS images.  The 256m slice, which has been enough for me, is US$20/mo -- it is cheaper than keeping an old box plugged in, and easy to back up.  Very easy to recommend.

Comment: Does it provide shell access that isn't through an ajax user interface?

Comment: Slicehost, and other VPS vendors, typically provide root ssh access to your virtual machine. I second this answer. For my money, a VPS is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Plug plug for [PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com), our own modest offering in this space.

We offer free hosting for basic web apps, with 1-click config for popular frameworks like Django, Flask, Web2py etc.  MySql is included, and you also get  full suite of browser-based development tools like an editor and a console...

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com/) for years and very happy with the service. They are not only python oriented. You should be able to run anything within the limitations of shared hosting (unless of course you have a dedicated server).

They are probably not the cheapest hosting service though. I don't know the prices. But I can still remember very well my previous hosting provider was unreachable for a week (not their servers, I mean the people).

Answer (score 0):

I've been pretty happy with Dreamhost, and of course Google AppEngine.

Comment: Why do many complain about Dreamhost's non-PHP application support, especially Django?

Comment: Damnfiknow.  They don't provide a django one-click install.

Comment: Personally, I found the Dreamhost experience terrible. They do have 'wizards' and workarounds for a lot of stuff, but there's always those edge cases that are excrutiating or impossible in a non-VPS scenario. E.g. installing Trac. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Google App engine and OpenHosting.com

Have virtual server by OpenHosting, they are ultra fast with support and have very high uptime.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://pythonplugged.com/

They are trying to collect information on Python hosting providers using variuos technologies (CGI, FCGI, mod_python, mod_wsgi, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to have a look at http://www.python-cloud.com

This PaaS platform can automatically scale up and down your application regarding your traffic. You can also finely customize if you want vertical, horizontal or both types of scalability. The consequence of this scaling is that you pay as you go : you only pay for your real consumption and not the potential one.

Deployment via git.

Non AWS, hosted in tier-4+ datacenters.

Free trial ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use AWS micro server, 1 year free and after that you can get a 3 year reserved which works out to about $75/yr :)  The micro server has only 20MB/sec throughput, ~600MB of ram, and a slower CPU. I run a few Mezzanine sites on mine and it seems fine.